# Is it academic misconduct to post assignment solutions on public websites?

Tags: ethics, policy

I belong to Computer Science background, and most of my assignments are programming based. I usually use Github(private repos) to maintain assignments during the semester. Since I only have limited private repos, I usually make the code public once the semester is over.  In a few subjects, the assignments remain same over semesters but usually the instructor use tools to check for plagiarism from previous submitted assignments for the new submissions.

Seeing this question, [Are there universities that consider it academic misconduct for students to publish material created by faculty?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28206/are-there-universities-that-consider-it-academic-misconduct-for-students-to-publ). I became curious that whether posting solutions to assignments of courses comes under academic misconduct or dishonesty ?

Comment: Even if it does not the breach the letter of the rules (which might vary between universities), it is wise to ask your instructors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there universities that consider it academic misconduct for students to publish material created by faculty?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28206/are-there-universities-that-consider-it-academic-misconduct-for-students-to-publ)

Comment: @BobBrown the programming assignment questions are from faculty or some online resource, but the solutions are entirely of my own.

Comment: @krammer: Then, if a faculty member should re-use an exercise, as you say happens, your having posted the solution would give others an unfair advantage and would be academic misconduct.

Comment: @BobBrown Disagree. See my answer below.

Comment: @krammer: So, if you posted the bare solutions, you haven't violated anyone's copyright.  If, OTOH, you posted problems with solutions, then you've violated the copyright of the person who wrote the problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I became curious that whether posting solutions to assignments of courses comes under academic misconduct or dishonesty ?

Generally, I would say that putting material online is **not** academic misconduct or dishonest. What is important in the question that you have linked is that the "dishonest" part for the student is not that he wanted to take material from the web (this may or may not be against the rules, but it is by itself not dishonest), but that he intended to **pretend** that he solved the assignments independently. Strictly speaking, I see it not as your responsibility to make sure that students that later on take inspiration from (or outright copy) your solution declare that they did so.

Of course, from a practical point of view, your behaviour may still be somewhat unpopular with your professors, as it clearly opens up additional venues for cheating for the next batches of students. Personally, as a lecturer, I was never bothered, because I strongly believe that you always need to assume that the solutions to an assignment that you "recycle" from the previous year are "out there" in one way or another. However, I know that other lecturers feel differently, so if you want to piss nobody off, you should check with the professors beforehand. In any way you should make sure that you are not uploading material that you do not possess the copyright for (for instance, lecture material or assignment descriptions).

Comment: At least where I teach, aiding another in committing misconduct is itself misconduct.

Comment: +1 for "assume it's out there one way or another." I know of a case where the TA was handed in their *own* program, since it had accidentally ended up visible and indexed by Google.  Needless to say, the cheater was instantly caught and faced disciplinary action.

Comment: @BobBrown By your rationale, anyone who puts any material online that might be of use to any student who isn't supposed to use online resources in completing an assignment, is committing misconduct.

Comment: @ff524: Incorrect.  By my rationale, anyone who puts on line solutions to specific homework problems is committing academic misconduct.